# Doxygen: how to document a non-C function using only its documentation block but not the code?

Tags: doxygen, pari

I want Doxygen to document the code written in C-like language (PARI/GP) but having slightly different syntax. I believe Doxygen can document the entities those do not exist. It seems to be the simplest way to do the job while the programming language is not Doxygen-supported. I want something like this:

```
/*!
 \fn foo(param,{option})
 \brief some brief description here
 \param[in](param) mandatory parameter description
 \param[in](option) optional parameter description
*/
/*! \cond DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS */
foo(param, {option}) =
{
    ...
};
addhelp(foo, "help message for `foo` function");
/*! \endcond */
```

Unfortunately, Doxygen generates the warning "documented symbol 'foo' was not declared or defined" and does not list the `foo` in an output HTML. Is there any way to force the Doxygen to produce the proper HTML using only the documentation blocks but not the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various options

1. You could write an input filter that translates your code into something that looks enough like C for doxygen to parse it (see also [FILTER_PATTERNS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_filter_patterns) and [EXTENSION_MAPPING](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extension_mapping)).
2. You could create a dummy C file with the function prototypes and document those instead. You could put the documentation in the C file or in your programming language if you use the approach you mentioned in the question.
3. If your language supports a C preprocessor, you could use doxygen's C preprocessor to hide parts of the file from doxygen, i.e.

   ```
   #if DOXYGEN_ONLY
   /**
    \brief some brief description here
    \param[in](param) mandatory parameter description
    \param[in](option) optional parameter description
   */
   void foo(param,option);
   #endif
   foo(param, {option}) { ... };
   ```

   and then define the following in the config file:

   ```
   PREDEFINED = DOXYGEN_ONLY
   ```

Comment: FILTER_PATTERNS works for me. As for me, it takes a small effort to write a Perl translator of the PARI/GP user-defined functions to their C prototypes.